# double type Functor definition refused

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-errors, functor

why is this functor definition refused ?

```
data Second a b = Ok a b | Ko a b deriving (Show)

instance Functor (Second x) where
  fmap f (Ok a b ) = Ok (f a) b
  fmap f (Ko a b ) = Ko a (f b)
```

I [get a lot of errors](https://repl.it/repls/ValidOffbeatWreckfish):

```
GHCi, version 8.0.1

main.hs:4:22: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘x’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> Second x a -> Second x b
        at main.hs:4:3
      ‘x’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the instance declaration at main.hs:3:10
      Expected type: Second x b
        Actual type: Second b a
    • In the expression: Ok (f a) b
      In an equation for ‘fmap’: fmap f (Ok a b) = Ok (f a) b
      In the instance declaration for ‘Functor (Second x)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        a :: x (bound at main.hs:4:14)
        f :: a -> b (bound at main.hs:4:8)
        fmap :: (a -> b) -> Second x a -> Second x b (bound at main.hs:4:3)
main.hs:4:28: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘x’
      ‘x’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the instance declaration at main.hs:3:10
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> Second x a -> Second x b
        at main.hs:4:3
    • In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘a’
      In the first argument of ‘Ok’, namely ‘(f a)’
      In the expression: Ok (f a) b
    • Relevant bindings include
        b :: a (bound at main.hs:4:16)
        a :: x (bound at main.hs:4:14)
        f :: a -> b (bound at main.hs:4:8)
        fmap :: (a -> b) -> Second x a -> Second x b (bound at main.hs:4:3)
```

What does this all mean? Please help.

Comment: The compiler gives an explanation (i.e. the errors).

Comment: You can fix this in a few ways: change `Ok (f a) b` to `Ok a (f b)`; or change `Second a b = Ok a b | Ko a b` to `Second a b = Ok b a | Ko a b`; or change to `Second a = Ok a a | Ko a a` and replace `Second x` with `Second`

Comment: You might want to make `Second` a bifunctor instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you unpack the definition of `Functor` you'll see that `Second`'s first parameter is kept the same, while its second parameter is up for transformation.

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (s -> t) -> f s -> f t
```

(where I've renamed type variables `a` and `b` to `s` and `t`, respectively, because you also have value variables `a` and `b`.)

That `class` gives us, in your specific `instance`

```
instance Functor (Second x) where
  -- fmap :: (s -> t) -> (Second x) s -> (Second x) t
  --    i.e. (s -> t) -> Second x s   -> Second x t
```

Now, when you implement `fmap`, you have to make sure that the *users* of `fmap` can choose any `x`, `s` and `t` they want. So you must make no assumptions about them: they stand for arbitrary, possibly different types. That's what the error messages mean when they talk about "rigid" type variables: *your* code is not allowed to choose specific types for them, so that its users can. The compiler is complaining that you are promising a *very polymorphic* function, but delivering a less polymorphic function which typechecks only when `x=s=t`.

That is, when you write

```
  fmap f (Ok a b) = Ok (f a) b
```

you have

```
f :: s -> t
Ok a b :: Second x s
a :: x
b :: s
```

and you are returning

```
Ok (f a) b :: Second x t
```

which would need

```
f a :: x   -- clearly not true, as f :: s -> t
b :: t     -- clearly not true, as b :: s
```

where `f a` needs

```
a :: s     -- clearly not true, as a :: x
```

So, yes, lots of errors.

A `Functor` instance lets you transform data in positions corresponding to the type's *last* parameter, i.e., the `b` in

```
data Second a b = Ok a b | Ko a b deriving (Show)
```

so your

```
  fmap f (Ko a b ) = Ko a (f b)
```

is just fine, but your

```
  fmap f (Ok a b ) = Ok (f a) b
```

hits the usage of a different parameter and is not ok.

```
  fmap f (Ok a b ) = Ok a (f b)
```

would work. As would changing the `data` declaration to

```
data Second a b = Ok b a | Ko a b deriving (Show)
```

and leaving your `instance` as it is.

Either fix works, but don't do both "just to be on the safe side"!